# Onclick anchor tag, change the title in span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a span like: Home in HTML page. and anchor tag like this: Introductiondemo.My question is that how can i change title "Home" in Span and replace with anchor title when the user clicks on anchor tag.

Comment: Could you perhaps show us some html code and possibly the javascript/jQuery you have tried so far? that would be lovely.....oh and ACCEPT some answers please!

Comment: <span id="module-titles">Home</span>
<a href="#module1-introduction">Introduction</a><a href="#module1-home">demo</a>

Comment: We edited your question so that people would be able to see the minimal amount of code you've provided. Why did you roll back so that we can no longer see this code?

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this?

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function() {
    $('#module-titles').html( $(this).html() );
});
```

Comment: needs to be change in span..how?

Comment: @thirupathi He is changing the contents of span? `$('#module-titles')` selects your span by it's id David is using `.html()` to sets it's contents with the contents of the anchor tag just clicked. In this instance `$(this).html()` refers to the contents of the anchor tag that has just been clicked

Comment: right i need to change content of that span with Anchor name, when the user clicks on anchor.Still struck....any help

Comment: @thirupathi: as far as I understand, my code does what you're asking. if you need more help, it might be a good idea to explain in more detail what you want. Specifically, when you click on an anchor, the content of the span will be updated to that of the anchor name. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/3d8yP/)

Answer (score 0):

Add class to `<a>` tag

```
 <a href="#module1-introduction" class="mod">Introduction</a>
 <a href="#module1-home" class="mod">demo</a>
```

And try this jquery

```
$('.mod').click(function(){
    $('#module-titles').html($(this).html());
 })
```

Comment: How come?.. I jus tried it again. Its working fine. Try here http://jsfiddle.net/NTvxD/

Answer (score 0):

just use the [start with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector

```
$('a[href^="#module1-"]').click(function() {  

    $('#module-titles').text($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easy with jquery do something like this
Your anchor tags should have ids

```
<a href="#module1-introduction" id = "module1-introduction">Introduction</a>
<a href="#module1-home" id = "module1-home">demo</a>

$('#module1-introduction , #module1-home').click(function(){
     var new_text = $(this).html();   
     $('#module-titles').html(new_text); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are after the anchor title and not the anchor content (which is what you said in your question) then it's something like tghis you should use.

```
$('a').on('click', function() {
    $('#module-titles').html(this.title);
});
```

If it's the content your are after then other answer will do, but you should update your question then.